# Strange SQL Remote Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

[image]

I have this remote query (`select * from dbo.prod_Enertia_emk_monthly_gas_interface`) with the linked server as LIVEDB.  How does SQL know to use the bottom selected query to the remote server?  I am puzzled as I have never created a remote query before.  How does this call work?

Comment: Is dbo.prod_Enertia_emk_monthly_gas_interface actually a view to a linked server?

Comment: I looked for object dbo.prod_Enertia_emk_monthly_gas_interface on both local and remote server and cannot find anything.

Comment: I search both servers and cannot find the view

Comment: It might be a synonym. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628061/creating-a-linked-server-and-database-alias

Comment: The call goes to a view named pdRptEMK3MonthlyGasProdcution on LIVEDB

Comment: SELECT name, base_object_name FROM sys.synonyms

Comment: SQL call object dbo.prod_Enertia_emk_monthly_gas_interface but does a remote call to "PRD_enertia"."dbo"."pdRptEMK3MonthlyGasProduction2" which is a view on remote server

Comment: The engine needs to know how many columns and which types he's gonna get with your *, so it does a few metadata queries before actually sending the command. This is the result of those queries.

Comment: So where can I find how object dbo.prod_Enertia_emk_monthly_gas_interface relates to the remote query?

Comment: Where does SQL store synonym?

Comment: I see it in SQL Server Management Studio as a folder under each database. Did that query show there were synonyms?

Comment: Thanks to all.  It is a SQL synonyms.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is either a view or a synonym. Both can be found in SQL Server Management Studio under the database in question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The remote call is using a synonyms.